# Options for returning nested SQL data structure in ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ado.net

I have three simple tables:

```
Employees

EmployeePhones

EmployeeEmails
```

Each employee has multiple emails and phones.  What are the options for getting all Employees and all of their phones and emails using ADO.NET and stored procedures.  I'm basically trying to fill a structure similar to this for every employee (very simplified):

```
public class Recipient
{
    public Employee RecipientEmployee { get; set; }

    public List<EmployeeEmail> RecipientEmails { get; set; }

    public List<EmployeePhone> RecipientPhones { get; set; }
}
```

One option is to make an initial database call to get all employees.  Then iterate over each employee and make additional calls to get each employees phones and emails.  Obviously in doing this, I will have an initial database call plus at least one additional call for each employee returned.  There could be a lot of employees.

Another option is making three DB calls to get all employees, all phones, all emails, and intersecting the three datasets somehow.

What are the other options?

Project is written using C# ADO.NET calling stored procedures in SQL Server 2008.  Solution should do the same.

Comment: If you are willing to do some extra work on the C# side, you can simply return the contents of the three tables by performing three `SELECT`s in the stored procedure. The C# code would have to use [`NextRecordset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to advance from one result set to the next. It reduces the number of round trips needed, duplicate data returned by joining the data, and can isolate the app from changes in the data, but leaves the app to piece the relationships back together. Or do the joins and get back XML?

Comment: Good idea.  I was thinking of something along the same lines but using a DataSet with multiple tables, you reminded me NextResult was available using a reader.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you do a `JOIN` between all the table something like below and then return a single record set from your procedure which then you can store in your application in `DataSet` or `DataTable` (Assuming that all those 3 tables do have relationship between them defined)

```
select e.name, e.age, e.city,
ep.primaryphone, ee.primaryemail
from Employees e join EmployeePhones ep on e.id = ep.eid
join EmployeeEmails ee on e.id = ee.eid;
```

Per your latest comment a sample query with `group by`:

```
select e.name, e.age, e.city,
ep.primaryphone, ee.primaryemail
from Employees e join 
( select eid, primaryphone
    from EmployeePhones 
   group by eid ) ep on e.id = ep.eid
join (
  select eid, primaryemail
   from EmployeeEmails 
   group by eid ) ee on e.id = ee.eid;
```

Comment: All tables have relationships.  Each employee could have an unknown number of phones and unknown number of emails.  Is this the best way to handle it?  Return duplicate employees and aggregate the results on employee id?

Comment: AFAIK, this is the best way; performing the DB calculation at DB end then in application end. Moreover, if you have duplicates (if it's really) then that can be taken care of in your `SELECT` query using some analytical/window function

Comment: Yes, my test data returns as many as 8 results for a single employee when just joining the tables up.  Multiple phones and multiple emails per employee.  I'm curious whether the aggregation of a large dataset to get the unique emails and unique phones from the duplicate rows will be faster than multiple db calls.  Will have to test.

Comment: Hmm, not sure but may be you are doing something wrong with your query but can't say for sure without seeing your query + table structure + sample data; but by any means you should never do multiple DB calles since that's much resource intensive. You may like to post a separate question with query + table structure + sample data; if you feel there is something wrong.

Comment: The query you posted is working as expected for me.  However, EmployeePhones and EmployeeEmails contains multiple records for each employee.  Duplicates are expected here I believe.

Comment: Ahh!! that can easily be solved using a `group by`. See edit in answer if that helps.